# VHDL Compiler exiting

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

I just want to run the test bench but I got this. Any one knows why? It's a simple code.

What test benches always have:

```
LIBRARY ieee;                                               
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;                                

ENTITY serpar3_vhd_tst IS
END serpar3_vhd_tst;
ARCHITECTURE serpar3_arch OF serpar3_vhd_tst IS
-- constants
```

Giving "periodo" the value of 20ns:

```
constant periodo: time:= 20ns
```

And giving some variables a start value:

```
-- signals                                                   
SIGNAL a : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL b : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL clk : STD_LOGIC:='0';
SIGNAL rst : STD_LOGIC:='1';
SIGNAL x : STD_LOGIC:='1';
COMPONENT serpar3
    PORT (
    a : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    b : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    c : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    rst : IN STD_LOGIC;
    x : IN STD_LOGIC
    );
END COMPONENT;
BEGIN
    i1 : serpar3
    PORT MAP (
-- list connections between master ports and signals
    a => a,
    b => b,
    c => c,
    clk => clk,
    rst => rst,
    x => x
    );
```

Reset process:

```
init : PROCESS
BEGIN                                                        
wait for periodo;
rst<=not(rst);        -- code that executes only once                      
WAIT;                                                       
END PROCESS init;
```

Clock process:

```
always : PROCESS      BEGIN                                                         
wait for periodo*0.5;
clk<=not(clk);                                                  
END PROCESS always;
```

Giving "x" some values:

```
xpr: process
begin
wait for periodo;
x<='1';
wait for periodo;
x<='1';
wait for periodo;
x<='0';
wait for periodo;
x<='1';
wait for periodo;
x<='0';
end process xpr;
END serpar3_arch;
```

Error msg:

```
# ** Error: C:/Users/EDUARDO/Documents/PUCP/2016-1/Circuitos Digitales/Random VHDL/serpar3/simulation/modelsim/serpar3.vht(91): VHDL Compiler exiting
# ** Error: C:/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/vcom failed.
```

Comment: Please combine all your snippets to a single file / code block, which forms a minimal example, so we can compile it on our local machines. You can embedded your documenting comments as *VHDL comments*. What is a *.vht file?

Comment: There's a missing space between the abstract literal 20 and the identifier ns (Modelsim doesn't care about this, it isn't standard compliant here). Also the constant declaration should be followed by a semicolon. Fixing these two things and your code (concatenated snippets) analyzes. Which is line 91?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after: `constant periodo: time:= 20ns`

Comment: Sorry, the web didn't allowed me combine it all saying it was too long for a code block, will embed it next time. Thanks for the support guys.